# Is it correct to phrase a declarative statement in interrogative form?

Tags: word-order, questions

Growing up in a country where English is not the native language, I always hear people phrase declarative statements in an interrogative form. I'm not sure if it's grammatically correct to do so.

Example in Question Form:

> What **will he** do, I wonder?

Declarative(What I hear from others):

> I wonder what **will he** do.

Based on what I have known all my life, I would phrase it as such:

> I wonder what **he will** do.

... While I am sure that the way I constructed it is correct, I'm not sure if one could phrase it the way they do.

Comment: "I wonder, what will he do?" is fine, at least as dialogue.  As a written statement you are right and it would be better to say "I wonder what he will do."

Comment: The matrix clause may be declarative, but the subordinate clause is interrogative. "What he will do" is an interrogative complement clause: the meaning here is "I wonder about the answer to the question 'What will he do?"'

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two statements.

First, a declarative statement:

> Of course it is grammatically correct to do so.

Second, an interrogative statement:

> Of course it is grammatically correct to do so?

*Any* declarative statement may be turned into a question by a rising modulation of the voice (signified in text by means of a question mark). There are other ways to form interrogatories, but they do not rule out this one.

[Related discussion on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71193/punctuating-question-tags-a-question-mark-is-always-required-isnt-it-well).